# AS3 erase bitmap that has filters

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, sprite, erase

So I use bitmap.bitmapData.draw(erase,null,null,"erase"); to erase part of a bitmap that has the sprite called erase over it. The problem is that I need the bitmap to be blurred, and after I apply a blur filter the bitmapData.draw function doesn't work anymore. Meaning absolutely nothing happens. I tried using bitmapdata.applyFilter, which almost works except when I erase near a blurred edge it "unblurs" itself.

```
        var erase:Sprite=new Sprite();
        erase.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        var blur:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter(10,10,10);
        var blurs:Array=new Array();
        blurs.push(blur);
        bitmap=new Bitmap(bitmapdata);
        bitmap.blendMode = "layer";
        bitmap.y=-10;
        bitmap.x=-10;
        Refs._stage.addChildAt(bitmap,0);
```

also:

```
                erase.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
                erase.graphics.drawCircle(stage.mouseX+10,stage.mouseY+10,35);
                erase.filters = blurs;
                erase.graphics.endFill();
                bitmap.bitmapData.draw(erase,null,null,"erase");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just how the erase draw works. It erases pixels based on the alpha value of the object being drawn in erase mode. Where the alpha is above 0.5, that pixel get its alpha dropped to zero. Other pixels are not touched. This is what you experience when you draw with erase, then blur, then draw with erase again. No, Flash is not intelligent enough to do erase-blur, you might have to do it yourself. You might try drawing a transparent BitmapData with `BlendMode.ERASE` to do a blur-erase, but I don't expect it to return a blurred bitmap with blurred erased regions.